How are ideals that generate isomorphic algebras related?
Given the tensor algebra $T(V)$ for a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, and ideals $I_1,I_2\in T(V)$ (I only care about quadratic ones, if that matters), how are $I_1$ and $I_2$ related if I have that
$$T(V)/I_1\simeq T(V)/I_2, $$
and they have the same Hilbert-Poincaré series, i.e., they are isomorphic as graded algebras?

Do you assume anything about the isomorphism?  Otherwise I'd suspect that there's very little you can say.

In addition to what @LSpice said, I suspect that this problem is undecidable in general. Note that a similar problem, namely, the word problem for groups, is undecidable.

I’m not sure how this has anything to do with the word problem. This is more like the isomorphism problem.

I want them to have the same Hilbert-Poincaré series. I will add this to the original question.
